# VBA Consolidate Information for the same ID's from 2 Worksheets on a 3rd Sheet

Tags: arrays, string, vba

After a lot of googling and trying I am asking you for help regarding the following Problem.

- **Worksheet 1** (Database) has the **ID's** and a lot of Information in **Column D**
- **Worksheet 2** (Skills) has the **ID's** in **Row 1** and all **respective skills** in the **rows below** the column for each ID.
- **Worksheet 3 (Output)** is needed to populate Listboxes and Graphs and can be considered empty

For Illustration purposes: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOSlX.jpg

Via **comboboxes**, the **skill** the user is looking for is **selected**. This Skill **then** needs to be **matched** **against** the skills of **each ID** on **Worksheet 2**.

**If a match** is found, the respective ID shall be found on **Worksheet 1** and certain **Information from there** copied **to Worksheet 3**.

My take on this has been to find each ID in Worksheet 1, match it with all ID's on Worksheet 2 and look through the respective rows for a match. However, every more efficient way is welcome.

Here my code:

*The comboboxes*

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Dim ws1, ws2, ws3, ws4 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("Meta DB")
Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("Criteria")
Set ws3 = wb.Worksheets("Supplier Criteria TreeView")
Set ws4 = wb.Worksheets("Supplier Skills")

'1. - - get all Suppliers for the selected Input
'Redefine for clarity
Dim strFind As String

'1.0. - - Clear previously used ranges
ws3.Range("A2:L28").Clear
ws3.Range("A30:L100").Clear
ws3.Range("V2:V20").Clear

'1.1. - - Get value to search for and range to go through (depending on combobox selections)
If Me.comboProduct.ListIndex = -1 And Me.comboSubGroup.ListIndex = -1 And Me.comboCG.ListIndex <> -1 Then
    strFind = Me.comboCG.value
ElseIf Me.comboProduct.ListIndex = -1 And Me.comboSubGroup.ListIndex <> -1 And Me.comboCG.ListIndex <> -1 Then
    strFind = Me.comboSubGroup.value
ElseIf Me.comboProduct.ListIndex <> -1 And Me.comboSubGroup.ListIndex <> -1 And Me.comboCG.ListIndex <> -1 Then
    strFind = Me.comboProduct.value
End If
```

**Try 1:**

```
Dim rng1, rng2 As Range
Dim lRow, j, k As Long
Dim IDrow As String

'Paste starting at row 2 or 30 in ws3, respectively (Active / Inactive)
j = 2
k = 30

For Each rng1 In ws1.Range("D4:D500")
    If Rng <> "" Then
        For Each rng2 In ws4.Range("A1:ZZ1")
            If rng2 <> "" Then
                If rng1.value = rng2.value Then
                    For lRow = 2 To ws4.UsedRange.Rows.Count
                        IDrow = ws4.Cells(lRow, rng2).value
                        If InStr(1, IDrow, strFind, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                            'Check for active Supplier in current Database-row
                            If ws1.Range("E" & rng1) = "Yes" Then
                                'Copy row of Database to row j of ws3 then increment j
                                ws1.Range("B" & rng1 & ":" & "E" & rng1).Copy Destination:=ws3.Range("B" & j & ":" & "E" & j) 'Copy Name, Potential Supplier, ID, Active
                                j = j + 1
                            'ElseIf inactive Supplier, post further down from 30 onwards. Second listbox populates from there
                            ElseIf ws1.Range("E" & rng1) = "No" Then
                                ws1.Range("B" & rng1 & ":" & "E" & rng1).Copy Destination:=ws3.Range("B" & k & ":" & "E" & k) 'Copy Name, Potential Supplier, ID, Active
                                k = k + 1
                            Else
                                Exit Sub
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next lRow
                End If
            End If
        Next rng2
    End If
Next rng1
```

**Try 2:**

```
Dim IDAr, MyAr, TempAr As Variant
Dim lRow, lastRow, entryrow, LCol, e As Long
Dim ColumnLetter As String

entryrow = ws3.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1

ws1LRow = ws1.Range("D" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
IDAr = ws1.Range("D4:D" & lRow).value


Set f = ws4.Range("A1:ZZ1").Find(What:=IDAr, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
ColumnLetter = Split(f.Address, "$")(1)

lastRow = ws4.Range(ColumnLetter & "2:" & ColumnLetter & "50").End(xlUp).row

MyAr = ws4.Range(ColumnLetter & "1:" & ColumnLetter & lastRow).value

With ws3
    'If IsArray(MyAr) Then
        For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
            TempAr = Split(MyAr(i, 1), "\")
            For e = 0 To 2
                TempAr(e) = ValueToCompare
                    If InStr(1, ValueToCompare, strFind, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                        ws3.Range("B" & entryrow).value = "Test if it works"
                        '.
                        '.
                        '.
                    End If
            Next e
        Next i
```

Thank you all in advance for any tips!

Comment: You could use some worksheet functions in it, like match to find the ID, similarly match to find the skill in the row.  So rather than looping the column, then the row, you could say `lngFoundRow=application.worksheetfunction.match(strFindID,ws2.range(A:A),false)`  and then something like `lngFoundSkill = application.worksheetfunction.match(strFindSkill,ws2.range("a" & lngFoundRow & ":z" & lngFoundRow)`

Comment: First of all, thank you for taking your time to answer here. - - In your example, strFindID would then be the Array with all IDs from the Database? So the "IDAr" from my bottom try?

Comment: Your ID, would come from your loop in WS1, then you'd check for a match in WS2 for the ID, then when you get that match, its the row number in the range, so if match("1234",ws2.range(A:A),false) gave 100, your found row would be 100, then you'd look for the skill, in the range you require, say B:X of the same row, so match("Maths",ws2.range("B" & ROWFOUND & ":X" & ROWFOUND) then `ws2.range("A" & ROWFOUND & ":X" & ROWFOUND).copy ws3.location`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub CodeForLazyPoster()

Dim rIDs As Excel.Range
Dim ID As Excel.Range
Dim lFoundRow As Long

Set rIDs = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a1:a10")

For Each ID In rIDs

    lFoundRow = FindRow(ID)

    If lFoundRow > 0 Then

        If FindSkill("Maths", Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & lFoundRow)) Then

            '   Copy here


        End If

    End If

Next ID


End Sub

Function FindRow(strFind) As Long

FindRow = 0

On Error Resume Next

FindRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match( _
        strFind, Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("a1:a10"), False)

End Function

Function FindSkill(strSkill As String, rngLookIn As Excel.Range) As Boolean

Dim tmp As Integer

FindSkill = False

On Error GoTo eHandle

tmp = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(strSkill, rngLookIn, False)

FindSkill = True

Exit Function

eHandle:


End Function
```

Comment: Is that "Thanks"? :)

Comment: Could you just quickly elaborate what strSkill would be in your code? An array similar to the "MyAr" in the code I posted?

Comment: The skill you are looking for, as in MATHS